# angularjs service calling $location.path is it against best practices?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, anti-patterns, angular-services

I am using a service in angularJS where I call `$location.path` inside one method in order to make a route change after a success or failure response from another service internally. Is this against Angular's best practices?

Comment: I've used it often. I have seen the occasional comment to avoid it, but with no reason why. The only other option for some situations is using the actual target value in a link in HTML. Which I refuse to do. :-P

Comment: I'd say it violates some SOLID principals. I'd leave manipulation of the user experience to a controller

Comment: The controller should do this instead of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on inputs given by other members, calling `$location.path` inside a service is against Angular's best practices instead it should be called in a controller.

Comment: How can we reach controller after getting the result in a service. I am using $rootscope . $broadcast to reach the controller..and came to know that it is not good. So how should i pass the control to controller after getting result. Please help

Comment: @krishnajamavatoor you can send a callback function as an argument for a call to a service, so then the control flow will be passed back to the controller. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource